# Avoid exit application when press back button

Tags: android, stack

I don't know why every times I click default back button, it close my app immediately.

I don't use :

> _ android:noHistory="true" in Manifest xml file
>      _ newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) before start new
>   activity

My activity in Manifest xml file is:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.canvas_bar.member.MemberActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_member" >
</activity>
```

My backPress function:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
       Log.e("back", "Last matches : pressed accepted");
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

My Code of replacing Activity ( in a tab of Tabhost)

```
  public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) 
{
    try
    {
        View view =  getLocalActivityManager()
                    .startActivity(id,newIntent) 
                    .getDecorView();
        this.setContentView(view);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        String msg = e.getMessage();
        Log.d("Change Activity", msg);
    }
}
```

In Log Cat, it shows:

> TRACE stop requested, but not running

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the default behavior of `TabHost`. You are simply replacing `ContentView`. If you start another `Activity` like this-

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,YourClass.class));
```

where YourClass is a separate class then this problem won't happen but since you have replaced it in the same `Tab` the problem happens. A simple tweak would be to go back to the previous `Activity` explicitly. You can in your `onBackPressed` provide an `Intent` to go back to the previous `Activity`.

Edit-
You cannot obtain previous `Tab` but you can store the information yourself. Just keep a record of previous tab in your class that listens for `onTabChanged()`.

```
static TabHost mytabs;

mytabs = getTabHost();

mytabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {         

        Log.i("***Selected Tab", "Im currently in tab with index::" + mytabs.getCurrentTab());
    }       
});
```

You get your current tab so store it. When the next change occurs just retrieve the stored value and replace it with current value.

Comment: For example, I have 3 tab A, B, C. I go from tab A-> B ( no child activity is replace in any tab, just move btw tabs), the app is also closed. In this case, we can't know which one is the previous activity  without back stack.

Comment: I agree with you that in case replace activity in same Tab, we should go OnBackPressed to provide an Intent.

Comment: Let me try. What i'm worry now is stackOverFlowError if I don't use back stack wisely. I let u know result later. Thanks first.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see where the log comes. But the source code posted just uses default behavior, which is to stop the activity.

Try to comment out super.onBackPressed();

Comment: Agree that this way is not force stop app. But it can not come back to previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Post the code you use to start this activity. May be you finish() the calling activity after this is started. So pressing back may be closing the app, instead of going back to the previous activity.

Comment: No. I don't put finish after start activity. I have updated code above. Please take a look.

Comment: See the documentation http://bit.ly/1b0WlE5. I think you should set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP instead of using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

Comment: It does not work too. I think sth wrong with back stack. Bc, when back button is pressed, it will close the current activity, and start with activity on the top of stack. In case, there is nothing in stack, it'll close app.

Comment: If the Intent maps to a different activity component than is currently running, the current activity is finished and a new one started. Maybe this is what's happening